# java antidecompiler version 8 error corrupted or rename jar file

Tags: java

i use version 8.because ,I don't want them to be able to decompile it back into source code .
After the anti decompiler .
jar file does not run and the following error message is displayed.

```
 corrupted or rename jar file
unexpected invocation Target Exception.
```

Somebody help me.

Comment: If you don't want people to be able to decompile your class files: don't distribute them. That's the only way to guarantee they won't be able to do so.

Comment: Describe exactly what you did, i.e., program calls with all parameters, etc. Error messages in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common for obfuscators to mess up code that relies on reflection ... if you fail to exclude the names of packages / classes / methods / fields that your code accesses reflectively.  Obfuscators typically work by mangling the names of packages / classes / methods / fields.  That will break any code that depends on the original names.

The `InvocationTargetException` that you are seeing implies that something is going wrong in reflectively invoked code.